# Important question about svchost virus was closed

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/524418/is-this-blue-screen-caused-by-a-virus/524434#524434) and It was closed as a Exact duplicate of a question which does not resemble it at all. First of all, nowhere in [this "dupilcate question's" answers](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) does it mention the stop error my question was based on. Also, there is no mention on the specific virus I was dealing with that I asked the question about. The answers were irrelevant to my situation. How do I report the five guys that closed this, and how can I reopen it?

Comment: Never remove the duplicate question reference from a post. I rolled the question back to when it was inserted. Feel free to bring back your changes from the [revisions page](http://superuser.com/posts/524418/revisions) now.

Comment: Can I still change the title?

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Just the note at the top is important *while* the question is closed. Once and if the question is reopened, it will be removed automatically.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didnt realize it was placed automatically, I thought someone had edited it into there.

Comment: Could you please not post your answer in the question, but use the "Answer your question" button to add the answer there?

Comment: Ok, when I have some time I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I think closing it as a duplicate was slightly overzealous. The question yours was closed as a duplicate of has a lot of good information, but is meant to be a general reference, not the end-all be-all for every virus question ever.

Generally speaking, when one is asking a question about a virus, they should try the main concepts listed in the referenced how to deal with viruses post. *If* that doesn't work, or if there ends up being a very particular way to remove the infection, then creating a new question for it is appropriate. Just make sure to reference the canonical virus removal question and say something to the effect of "I tried <all this> and it didn't work" so that it doesn't get closed as a dupe.

For the reasons above, I reopened your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on the question to add the stuff it needs.